# Increasing size of possible partition - deleting content index file

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-management

Trying to create a new partition from within Win7 to install a linux system on.

I disabled the page file, disabled hibernation, disabled restoration (intending to re-enable them once the new partition is created, don't worry), then defragmented ... still, diskmgmt tells me I can't create larger than 20Gb a partition, even though I freed about 140Gb worth of space.

So I took a look at the event viewer ...

Last unmovable file:
`\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Projects\SystemIndex\Indexer\CiFiles\00010002.wid::$DATA`

How do I best get rid of that context index file?

**Edit**: Boot defragmentation using UltraDefrag didn't help either.

Comment: You are doing a boot time defrag?

Comment: nope, that was simply Win7's defrag utility. You think i should try with UltraDefrag, for example?

Comment: Default tool can defrag at boot.  Use the tool of your choice.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to make any difference. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Disabled Windows Search or manually delete them

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678867%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That got me about 1Gb worth of space ... because now some undeletable fontcache files get in my way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd grown tired of windows' "unmovable" files. The more of them you delete, the more of them there seem to be, so I just created a linux live usb stick and created the partition from there.

Probably not the most elegant solution, but a lot faster than bothering with a "clean" way.